# Should tags [django-tests] and [django-testing] be merged?

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

These seem to me to be exact duplicates...

[Description of [django-tests]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-tests):

> Use for questions about testing applications based upon the Python web framework Django, or the features provided in the module itself (django.test)

[Description of [django-testing]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-testing):

> Django is a high-level Python Web framework that encourages rapid development and clean, pragmatic design. This tag is about writing and running tests for your Django apps.

Do they not mean the same?

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the descriptions, they should be merged.